# 3.5" TFT LCD Display is not working with Arduino Mega 2560 R3

Tags: arduino-mega, shields, lcd, display

Even I can't do similarly with my 2.4" TFT LCD in here still: [2.4" TFT LCD Shield isn't working on Arduino Mega](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/2-4-tft-lcd-shield-isnt-working-on-arduino-mega)

Now, I have bought 3.5" TFT LCD display for my Arduino Mega 2560 R3 to try whether I could run the screen or not, and it is not working now! I am so depressed and angry for these two's misbehaviors. I have already checked website and a lot of Arduino IDE code examples and libraries such as UTFT.h, UTouch.h, UTFT_MEGA, UTFT_CTE, TFTLCD. I tried these and I can not run my 3.5" screen. Where am I faulty? There is something below the screen shield: www.mcufriend.com and 3.5" TFTLCD for Arduino 2560. Are there any basic code or have anyone tried to run Mcufriend's displays correctly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [2.4" TFT LCD Shield isn't working on Arduino Mega](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/2-4-tft-lcd-shield-isnt-working-on-arduino-mega)

Comment: I would recommend contacting the seller about example code/libraries, or at the least a datasheet.

Comment: I have the same problem and the seller does not respond

Comment: I know how to make these work, but they are all a little different. Please post a link to the exact product you bought. A link to an online store or something will work fine. If it's like the one in my photo, I can make it work... https://www.flickr.com/photos/77816686@N02/11719888193/in/set-72157636192458205

Comment: Yes it is @Jasmine. Please do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I still don't see a link to the product? I could write up a general approach, but it might be a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.henningkarlsen.com/electronics/library.php?id=51

Download hennings new UTFT library.

in myGLCD define R61581 as this is the driver chip for 3.5 display.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fce43rxofttl001/Librer%C3%ADas%20UTFT%20%2B%20UTouch%20para%203.5%20TFTLCD%20para%20Arduino%20Mega%202560%20%20-%20copia.rar

First delete the old UTFT library, then copy and paste the library inside de RAR file.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the file?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a silly suggestion, but the mega2560 is 5v, and the display is 3.3v...and you need an interface board between.  I have successfully run a 3.2" display using this interface board

http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/lcd-tft01-arduino-shield-v20-shd09-p-213.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have the same lcd shield from mcufriend. It has ILI9327 in 8 bit mode.

This shield doesn't work with original UTFT library (it supports only 16-bit mode).

Try modified version from https://github.com/dgolda/UTFT and use:

```
myGLCD(NIC35WS,38,39,40,41); //3.5" TFTLCD for arduino 2560 from mcufriend.com
```